# how to remove a file from input type file in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I have requirement where i have to upload multiple file and show in a list,if a file is invalid then a remove button displayed while clicking on remove button the file should be removed from filelist array.

i searched a lot but nothing work for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: *"nothing worked"*. We don't know what you tried so unless you show us you are likely to get all the same suggestions again